# Why did entity framework core pick "<EntityName>Name" over "Id" as the primary key column?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I added a new entity with this structure:

```cs
public class Domain
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string DomainName { get; set;
}
```

Once I ran the migration, i noticed that DomainName was the primary key.

I did add an index to the DomainName column:

```cs
builder.HasIndex(x => x.DomainName)
    .HasName("IX_Domain_DomainName")
    .IsUnique();
```

So how come the column called DomainName was chosen to be the primary key, over and above the one called Id?

Comment: What does the mapping code look like, for the index?

Comment: @GertArnold  Your question answered the question. Kind of. I had another entity called OrganisationDomain with a virtual property link to class Domain and a "DomainName" de-normalised property.
EF decided to create a foreign key based on that, although im still not sure of why.

Comment: Would be interesting to see all configuration pertaining to these classes so we can try to understand what EF is doing there and if it could be a bug.

Comment: @GertArnold I will have to attempt to reproduce it in a clean room environment, so I can give you the full code.

Comment: Make sure it becomes part of your question as a [mcve].

Comment: If there isn't a known answer in terms of an intentional feature, this would be better moved to an issue on the ef core github.

Comment: @gburton this is an intentional feature but there is a way to override this default logic using `key` which I've shown in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Include `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;` and add the `[Key]` decorator above where `Guid Id` is defined.

The Key attribute can be applied to a property in an entity class to make it a key property and the corresponding column to a PrimaryKey column in the database. The default convention creates a primary key column for a property whose name is Id or Id. (This is why DomainName was picked as the PK) The `[Key]` attribute decorator overrides this default convention.